# How to translate this Swift func to Xamarin.iOS/C#

Tags: c#, swift, xamarin

I'm working through an exercise at moment and want to translate this Swift func across to Xamarin.iOS/C#. I'll keep plugging away but if anyone can offer some help that would be awesome.

```
func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate
    <D: protocol<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>>
    (dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {

    collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.tag = row
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

what i can't work out is how that method signature in Swift, translates to C#

Piece of the signature that has me stumped at mom. is:

```
<D: protocol<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>>
```

The context - is that each row of a tableview, contains a collection view that scrolls horizontally. The func above, is called for each row in the *tableview*, via willDisplayCell. For example:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell:UITableViewCell, 
forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //code..

    tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)

}
```

Thanks to @Alexey. Updating for anyone else needing this info. This method, placed in the custom cell class worked nicely (I made use of the interfaces available for UICollectionViewDelegate/Datasource):

```
    public void SetCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<T>(T dataSourceDelegate, int row) where T : IUICollectionViewDelegate, IUICollectionViewDataSource  
    {
        collectionView.Delegate = dataSourceDelegate;
        collectionView.DataSource = dataSourceDelegate;
        collectionView.Tag = row;
        collectionView.ReloadData ();
    }
```

Comment: please add whatever you have tried till now.

Comment: please edit your question description and add whatever you have added in your comment above

Comment: any ideas at all ? driving me bonkers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<D>(
D dataSourceDelegate, 
int row)
where D : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate`
```

I don't know the equivalents of `UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate` types in Xamarin Forms, though. They should be interfaces of some sort.​

Comment: thanks so much. I'm not sure about UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate interface(s)... ill look into it now.. if anyone knows that would be big help I'm on bit of a time constraint :-)

Comment: worked perfectly thank you so much. i updated above w/ the complete method